# Access VBA, take table data and paste/insert it into another table at the end

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a dataset that is imported from excel into access in a new table. I want to take this data and "add it" to the end of a larger data set as the main table is updated daily with relevant information. Not too experienced with VBA, however, this I cannot wrap my head around as I am normally experienced with Excel. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help.

Comment: So, what is the real question? Otherwise I do not see any problem, just copy&paste the data where you want to have it. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I want to have a macro run from access to append the data into the other table

Comment: And I want you to try something first on your own. This is not a code writing service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [Add records to a table by using an append query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-98a5bd66-2190-4243-9638-8ef649cf3596)

Comment: Also http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm

Answer (score 0):

*...from excel into access in a new table..*. If the data is already in your Access database, just make an INSER INTO query. No need of VBA

> [Add records to a table by using an append
>   query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-98a5bd66-2190-4243-9638-8ef649cf3596?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

And after you are done, make sure you clear that temp table where you import your data, with another query that deletes all records.